# How to pass a parameter to a public static void main class?

Tags: java, automation

I have a question in passing a parameter to a public static void main class.

Basically I have the following main class here:

```
public class testClass{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
           ...//code

            String clientId = "test" + args0;

        ...
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Now I want to pass an id as args0 for the clientid. My attempt is to write a step definition like so:

```
When I enter the clientId "xxxxxx"
```

Then in my step def actually call on the main method but it's the below I am having trouble with. I know how to pass parameters from one method to another but how do I pass it in a main where we require an args?

```
@When("^I enter the clientId \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void ientertheClientId(String clientId)  {
    testClass.main(clientId);
}
```

Above gives me a red line for the method

Comment: Main takes an array of arguments, with each element representing one argument. So you just need to create an array of length one with the client ID and pass that.

Comment: Therefore it should also be args[0] instead of args0 (and maybe a check whether args is empty before that).

Comment: @floxbr I suspect the code he has omitted (`...//code`) is putting the first element into a variable.

Comment: Possibly, though I don't see the point of putting the content of args[0] into a local varible named args0. If you introduce a varibale, it should be named clientID or something like that (and the String be named differently as it also contains "test").

Comment: "I don't see the point" well, this isn't Code Review. From what they've told us, we have no reason to assume that their main method does not work correctly. Their problem is that they don't understand how to call it.

Comment: Ok then. Last suggestion from my part: replace main(String[] args) by main(String... args), then it also accepts a single String as an argument as ientertheClientId apparently tries to do.

Answer (score -2):

The function `ientertheClientId` must be `static` to call the function `main`.

Comment: @Ennosrep no, it doesn't. have to be.

Comment: @Michael how do you figure ientertheClientId to be static?

Comment: @Stultuske Oh, I misunderstood. I thought they thought `testClass` was an instance (which would still not prohibit calling a static method on it, of course). He's still wrong, just for different reasons than I thought

Comment: But that is simply wrong. We *can call* static functions from non-static functions. Same way we can access other static things like `out` from `System` class via `System.out` from *any* function.